# Verify Signed PE File

Tags: c, winapi, certificate, portable-executable, wincrypt

(Sorry for my bad English.) I have some problems in my code.so I will try to explain my problem. I have a simple exe file with signed(pkcs7). I want to verify this file (without an internet connection). I don't want to use `WinVerifyTrust()` because I want to know how windows verify PE file. I wrote some code that first calls `CryptQueryObject()` with BLOB_DATA(mapped pe file), and it works fine. Then I can get certificate information: signer, serial,  etc. (with `CryptGetMsgParam()`) and it also works fine; but, when I go to verify it with `CertGetCertificateChain()` I get and error. So, can you help me to solve this problem, which I think is that I don't use `CertGetCertificateChain()` correctly?

```c
BOOL bRet = FALSE;
DWORD dwMsgAndCertEncodingType = 0;
DWORD dwContentType = 0;
DWORD dwFormatType = 0;
HCERTSTORE  hStore = NULL;
HCRYPTMSG   hMsg = NULL;
PCCERT_CONTEXT      pCertContext = NULL;
CERT_BLOB   blob_data = { 0 };
// CERT_INFO    CertInfo = { 0 };
DWORD dwSignerInfo = 0;
PCCERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT pChainContext = NULL;
PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo = NULL;
CERT_CHAIN_PARA          ChainPara = { 0 };


blob_data.pbData = pBuff;
blob_data.cbData = dwSize;


ChainPara.cbSize = sizeof(CERT_CHAIN_PARA);


bRet = CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_BLOB,
    &blob_data,
    CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED,
    CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY,
    0,
    NULL,
    &dwContentType,
    NULL,
    &hStore,
    &hMsg,
    &pCertContext);


if (bRet != TRUE)
{
    printf("Error CryptQueryObject\n");
    return FALSE;
}


if (dwContentType != CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED)
{
    printf("Error type\n");
    return FALSE;
}


CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 0, NULL, &dwSignerInfo);

pSignerInfo = HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, dwSignerInfo);


CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 0, pSignerInfo, &dwSignerInfo);



bRet = CertGetCertificateChain(NULL, (PCCERT_CONTEXT)pCertContext, NULL, NULL, NULL, CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CACHE_ONLY,
    NULL, &pChainContext);

if (bRet != TRUE)
{
    printf("Error there\n");
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply. Yes it may be make problem but I actualy dont know how to use it because there aren't good information and net also I dont see any good examples (

Comment: OK, comment now moved to an answer, with some (hopefully useful) sample code.

Comment: hi, Amfield It's better to include the most basic error message in your question. Now that you call `CertGetCertificateChain` and there is an error, according to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certgetcertificatechain#return-value) prompt, for extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

Answer (score 1):

One problem (though maybe not the only one) is the fact that your fifth parameter to `CertGetCertificateChain()` is `NULL`? This should point to a `CERT_CHAIN_PARA` structure. (You have one declared but don't appear to either initialize or use it.)

I don't know exactly what data you should put in this, but here's an example using code taken from a real (working) program (one of my own making) that checks digital certificates:

```
//...
CERT_CHAIN_PARA ChainPara;  memset(&ChainPara, 0, sizeof(CERT_CHAIN_PARA));
ChainPara.cbSize = sizeof(CERT_CHAIN_PARA);
ChainPara.RequestedUsage.dwType = USAGE_MATCH_TYPE_AND;
ChainPara.RequestedUsage.Usage.cUsageIdentifier = 0;
//...
bRet = CertGetCertificateChain(NULL, (PCCERT_CONTEXT)pCertContext, NULL, NULL, &ChainPara,
    CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CACHE_ONLY, NULL, &pChainContext);
//...
```

You can look at the documentation for `CERT_CHAIN_PARA` to get some hints on what actual data/values you should set.

Hope this helps! (Feel free to ask for further clarification and or suggestions.)

Comment: Thank you Adrian but it doesnt help . I try Catalog Files maybe be it helps